# Eclipse runAction into a welcome page

Tags: html, eclipse

I'm developing an application based on eclipse and I've a welcome page with links ..using runAction fonction. It works very well except for this ex:

```
href="http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction?pluginId=com.blabla&amp;class=com.myclass.DefaultApplicationOpenerAction&amp;url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUFLq6dKQok" />
```

because the "=" split the parameter in the fonction getQueryParameters of IntroURLParser.
How can I do ?
maybe use another king of action ?

Many thanks for your help ... :)

Comment: Does `...url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DXUFLq6dKQok` work?

Comment: Yes :D thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

In parameter values `=` has to be encoded as `%3D`:

```
href="http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction?pluginId=com.blabla&amp;class=com.myclass.DefaultApplicationOpenerAction&amp;url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DXUFLq6dKQok" />
```

Comment: Yes thank you howlger !
it works very well :)